# Delete sublists containing strings

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list with several sublists containing *either* strings or integers. I'd like to delete all lists with strings.

The following list:

```
list = {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {2, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7}, {1, 23}, {"SomeString"}}
```

should become:

```
{{1, 2, 3, 4}, {2, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7}, {1, 23}}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an application for DeleteCases:

```
list = {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {2, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7}, {1, 23}, {"SomeString"}}

DeleteCases[list, {_String}]
```

Comment: Here you were faster... I would do the same, but with `__String` instead

Comment: :-). The field is now up to you. In Germany time to go to bed now, so keep on ...

Answer (score 2):

This removes all lists that contain at least one string, not just lists consisting of a single string:

```
Cases[list, _?(FreeQ[_String])]

(*  {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {2, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7}, {1, 23}}  *)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Select[list, FreeQ[_String]]
```

> {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {2, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7}, {1, 23}}

`FreeQ` is going to filter lists with any strings. In this particular case, it works well, but this may or may not be useful in all situations.

Answer (score 1):

Using `GroupBy` and `Lookup`:

```
Lookup[GroupBy[list3, AllTrue@StringQ], False]

(*{{1, 2, 3, 4}, {2, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7}, {1, 23}}*)
```